# Whats an easy way to totally ignore ssl with java url connections?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I'm building an application that periodically checks some rss feeds for new content. Some of these feeds are only reachable via https and some have self signed or somehow broken certificates. I want to be able to check them never the less.

Please note that security is not an issue in this application the goal is to access the content with minimal effort.

I'm using this code to circumvent most of the certificate issues:

```
/**
     * Sets timeout values and user agent header, and ignores self signed ssl
     * certificates to enable maximum coverage
     * 
     * @param con
     * @return
     */
    public static URLConnection configureConnection(URLConnection con)
    {
        con.setRequestProperty(
            "User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        con.setReadTimeout(40000);
        if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
        {
            HttpsURLConnection conHttps = (HttpsURLConnection) con;
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager()
            {

                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {
                }
            } };

            HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            try
            {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc
                    .getSocketFactory());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
                con = conHttps;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        return con;
    }
```

this works for most of the sites, but on one I still get this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification pat
h to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1715)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:257)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:251)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1168)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:963)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:397)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at crawler.RSSReader.getNewArticles(RSSReader.java:53)
        at crawler.Crawler.fetchFeed(Crawler.java:187)
        at crawler.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:324)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:224)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1147)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:197)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:255)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:319)
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: No because i want to read from this site. I'm ignoring it for the overall application but it does not solve the problem for the specific site. I cannot open an inputstream on this connection.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1201048/32453

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a solution at [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/WebObjects/Web_Services/How_to_Trust_Any_SSL_Certificate) which gracefully works for me. Just call

```
SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();
```

Before your SSL connection.

You can also capture more solution by searching Internet for `java ssl trustall`.

Here is the copy of that solution (in case of maybe a broken link in future):

```
 import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
 import java.security.SecureRandom;
 import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
 import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
 import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
 import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

 /**
  * This class provide various static methods that relax X509 certificate and 
  * hostname verification while using the SSL over the HTTP protocol.
  *
  * @author    Francis Labrie
  */
 public final class SSLUtilities {

   /**
    * Hostname verifier for the Sun's deprecated API.
    *
    * @deprecated see {@link #_hostnameVerifier}.
    */
   private static com.sun.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier __hostnameVerifier;
   /**
    * Thrust managers for the Sun's deprecated API.
    *
    * @deprecated see {@link #_trustManagers}.
    */
   private static com.sun.net.ssl.TrustManager[] __trustManagers;
   /**
    * Hostname verifier.
    */
   private static HostnameVerifier _hostnameVerifier;
   /**
    * Thrust managers.
    */
   private static TrustManager[] _trustManagers;


   /**
    * Set the default Hostname Verifier to an instance of a fake class that 
    * trust all hostnames. This method uses the old deprecated API from the 
    * com.sun.ssl package.
    *
    * @deprecated see {@link #_trustAllHostnames()}.
    */
   private static void __trustAllHostnames() {
       // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
       if(__hostnameVerifier == null) {
           __hostnameVerifier = new _FakeHostnameVerifier();
       } // if
       // Install the all-trusting host name verifier
       com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.
           setDefaultHostnameVerifier(__hostnameVerifier);
   } // __trustAllHttpsCertificates

   /**
    * Set the default X509 Trust Manager to an instance of a fake class that 
    * trust all certificates, even the self-signed ones. This method uses the 
    * old deprecated API from the com.sun.ssl package.
    *
    * @deprecated see {@link #_trustAllHttpsCertificates()}.
    */
   private static void __trustAllHttpsCertificates() {
       com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext context;

       // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
       if(__trustManagers == null) {
           __trustManagers = new com.sun.net.ssl.TrustManager[] 
               {new _FakeX509TrustManager()};
       } // if
       // Install the all-trusting trust manager
       try {
           context = com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
           context.init(null, __trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
       } catch(GeneralSecurityException gse) {
           throw new IllegalStateException(gse.getMessage());
       } // catch
       com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.
           setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
   } // __trustAllHttpsCertificates

   /**
    * Return true if the protocol handler property java.
    * protocol.handler.pkgs is set to the Sun's com.sun.net.ssl.
    * internal.www.protocol deprecated one, false 
    * otherwise.
    *
    * @return                true if the protocol handler 
    * property is set to the Sun's deprecated one, false 
    * otherwise.
    */
   private static boolean isDeprecatedSSLProtocol() {
       return("com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol".equals(System.
           getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs")));
   } // isDeprecatedSSLProtocol

   /**
    * Set the default Hostname Verifier to an instance of a fake class that 
    * trust all hostnames.
    */
   private static void _trustAllHostnames() {
       // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
       if(_hostnameVerifier == null) {
           _hostnameVerifier = new FakeHostnameVerifier();
       } // if
         // Install the all-trusting host name verifier:
       HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(_hostnameVerifier);
   } // _trustAllHttpsCertificates

   /**
    * Set the default X509 Trust Manager to an instance of a fake class that 
    * trust all certificates, even the self-signed ones.
    */
   private static void _trustAllHttpsCertificates() {
       SSLContext context;

       // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
       if(_trustManagers == null) {
           _trustManagers = new TrustManager[] {new FakeX509TrustManager()};
       } // if
       // Install the all-trusting trust manager:
       try {
       context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
       context.init(null, _trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
       } catch(GeneralSecurityException gse) {
           throw new IllegalStateException(gse.getMessage());
       } // catch
       HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.
           getSocketFactory());
   } // _trustAllHttpsCertificates

   /**
    * Set the default Hostname Verifier to an instance of a fake class that 
    * trust all hostnames.
    */
   public static void trustAllHostnames() {
       // Is the deprecated protocol setted?
       if(isDeprecatedSSLProtocol()) {
           __trustAllHostnames();
       } else {
           _trustAllHostnames();
       } // else
   } // trustAllHostnames

   /**
    * Set the default X509 Trust Manager to an instance of a fake class that 
    * trust all certificates, even the self-signed ones.
    */
   public static void trustAllHttpsCertificates() {
       // Is the deprecated protocol setted?
       if(isDeprecatedSSLProtocol()) {
           __trustAllHttpsCertificates();
       } else {
           _trustAllHttpsCertificates();
       } // else
   } // trustAllHttpsCertificates

   /**
    * This class implements a fake hostname verificator, trusting any host 
    * name. This class uses the old deprecated API from the com.sun.
    * ssl package.
    *
    * @author    Francis Labrie
    *
    * @deprecated see {@link SSLUtilities.FakeHostnameVerifier}.
    */
   public static class _FakeHostnameVerifier 
       implements com.sun.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier {

       /**
        * Always return true, indicating that the host name is an 
        * acceptable match with the server's authentication scheme.
        *
        * @param hostname        the host name.
        * @param session         the SSL session used on the connection to 
        * host.
        * @return                the true boolean value 
        * indicating the host name is trusted.
        */
       public boolean verify(String hostname, String session) {
           return(true);
       } // verify
   } // _FakeHostnameVerifier


   /**
    * This class allow any X509 certificates to be used to authenticate the 
    * remote side of a secure socket, including self-signed certificates. This 
    * class uses the old deprecated API from the com.sun.ssl 
    * package.
    *
    * @author    Francis Labrie
    *
    * @deprecated see {@link SSLUtilities.FakeX509TrustManager}.
    */
   public static class _FakeX509TrustManager 
       implements com.sun.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {

       /**
        * Empty array of certificate authority certificates.
        */
       private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = 
           new X509Certificate[] {};


       /**
        * Always return true, trusting for client SSL 
        * chain peer certificate chain.
        *
        * @param chain           the peer certificate chain.
        * @return                the true boolean value 
        * indicating the chain is trusted.
        */
       public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
           return(true);
       } // checkClientTrusted

       /**
        * Always return true, trusting for server SSL 
        * chain peer certificate chain.
        *
        * @param chain           the peer certificate chain.
        * @return                the true boolean value 
        * indicating the chain is trusted.
        */
       public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
           return(true);
       } // checkServerTrusted

       /**
        * Return an empty array of certificate authority certificates which 
        * are trusted for authenticating peers.
        *
        * @return                a empty array of issuer certificates.
        */
       public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
           return(_AcceptedIssuers);
       } // getAcceptedIssuers
   } // _FakeX509TrustManager


   /**
    * This class implements a fake hostname verificator, trusting any host 
    * name.
    *
    * @author    Francis Labrie
    */
   public static class FakeHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

       /**
        * Always return true, indicating that the host name is 
        * an acceptable match with the server's authentication scheme.
        *
        * @param hostname        the host name.
        * @param session         the SSL session used on the connection to 
        * host.
        * @return                the true boolean value 
        * indicating the host name is trusted.
        */
       public boolean verify(String hostname, 
           javax.net.ssl.SSLSession session) {
           return(true);
       } // verify
   } // FakeHostnameVerifier


   /**
    * This class allow any X509 certificates to be used to authenticate the 
    * remote side of a secure socket, including self-signed certificates.
    *
    * @author    Francis Labrie
    */
   public static class FakeX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

       /**
        * Empty array of certificate authority certificates.
        */
       private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = 
           new X509Certificate[] {};


       /**
        * Always trust for client SSL chain peer certificate 
        * chain with any authType authentication types.
        *
        * @param chain           the peer certificate chain.
        * @param authType        the authentication type based on the client 
        * certificate.
        */
       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, 
           String authType) {
       } // checkClientTrusted

       /**
        * Always trust for server SSL chain peer certificate 
        * chain with any authType exchange algorithm types.
        *
        * @param chain           the peer certificate chain.
        * @param authType        the key exchange algorithm used.
        */
       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, 
           String authType) {
       } // checkServerTrusted

       /**
        * Return an empty array of certificate authority certificates which 
        * are trusted for authenticating peers.
        *
        * @return                a empty array of issuer certificates.
        */
       public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
           return(_AcceptedIssuers);
       } // getAcceptedIssuers
   } // FakeX509TrustManager
 } // SSLUtilities
```

Comment: Guess everyone liked using something you say is useless. Maybe next time you can provide the solution.

Comment: @deFreitas, I did not need to check so far and don't know, sorry.

Comment: @YasserZamani I used this and I still get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert`. Any clue on what might be wrong?

Comment: @DavidFernandez , does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception work for you. Generally try googling "Received fatal alert".

Comment: I went through that answer and few others. This answer is very thorough and I expected it to 'just work'. I am doing a pretty standard https call with the same tooling exposed. I will go an create a question for it.