# HttpUrlConnection timeout even though page is available in the browser - JBoss issue?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to get page content from a specific URL:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
LOGGER.info("Response code: "+conn.getResponseCode();
... (rest of the code, not relevant at the moment) ...
```

I'm not able to get `conn.getResponseCode()`, I have timeout before it gets printed. Surprisingly, when I put the very same URL in my browser, the page will be loaded correctly. I thought it may have something do to with HTTP/HTTPS, unfortunately, after changing `HttpURLConnection` to `HttpsURLConnection` there is no difference.

Maybe it has something to do with JBoss configuration? I use JBoss 7.1.1 Final.

Comment: Have you tried this with other URLs? If the URL isn't something sensitive, it'd help if I could test it. Right now, with a random http url, your above code is giving me a 200 OK as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your suppourt. Unfortunately, it looks like none URL works fine.  I guess it may be the JBoss configuration issue. I will try this on my another server.

Comment: Is this server behind a HTTP proxy? Use of of proxies in your browser can be transparent, so you may not notice their presence.

Comment: Actually, there are multiple servers and we have a load balancer. I guess it may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an HTTPS url? If it is, you need to account for that. When using an HttpsURLConnection, you must account for the fact that HTTPS certificates need a truststore to compare against. To ignore this sense of trust (and somewhat ruin the point of using HTTPS), see [Whats an easy way to totally ignore ssl with java url connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257455/whats-an-easy-way-to-totally-ignore-ssl-with-java-url-connections)

Comment: Yeah, it is HTTPS. But after replacing HTTPS with HTTP I have the same result.