# Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:

Tags: xamarin.forms

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/146613/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception/p1?new=1

Im facing this issue in xamarin forms android somebody please guide me to resolve this

Comment: Is your server correctly setup? It can be an issue with the server and not with the application

Comment: we are using testing link without ssl certificate how to resolve this

Comment: is there is any parameter to avoid ssl certifcate verification

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21257694/3094731

Answer (score 0):

To disable SSL validation you can add this line to onCreate (MainActivity) and FinishedLaunching (AppDelegate).

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

If this doewsn't work, you can follow this [guide](https://softwareproduction.eu/2017/08/26/xamarin-on-android-bypass-ssl-verification-with-httpclient/)