# Java 6 or 7 HTTPS get post with TLSv1.2

Tags: java, sslsocketfactory

I have problem to connect on https get/post using tlsv1.2 via java.

Somebody have a guide or some examples that work?
I imported by keytool private and public key setted by password on keystore.
I used a SSLSocketFactory but I got only errors https (not handshake).
I added parameters in jvm -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2" to enable only version 1.2 of TLS.
But nothing ...

An example please or a guide from import certificate to implements the class and using SSLSocketFactory.

Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: I haven't handshake error...I get connection closed by peer http error 403

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 does NOT support tls1.2 [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https), if used java 6 you cannot enable TLS1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("cert.crt");

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(is);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null); // You don't need the KeyStore instance to come from a file.
ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);

tmf.init(ks);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

And to create SocketFactory

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally build my own "**TLSConnectionFactory**" based on BouncyCasttle Provider. The code is [shared here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517476/tls-1-2-java-1-6-bouncycastle)

So, after you can use this **TLSConnectionFactory** this simple and quick way:

```
     String httpsURL =  xxxxxxxxxx
    URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);      
    HttpsURLConnection  con = (HttpsURLConnection )myurl.openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(new TSLSocketConnectionFactory());   
    InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
```