# Java 1.6.30 TLS1.2

Tags: java, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I'm trying to use BouncyCastleProvider in order to connect with a page with the TLS1.2 certificate as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    final URL url = new URL("https://tls1test.salesforce.com/s/");
    final HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    final InputStream inputStream = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
}
```

But I'm receiving the error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

I'm using Java version 1.6_30.

What can I do?

Comment: Installing the BouncyCaste SecurityProvider enables BC for cryptographic primitives, but AFAIK not for TLS (because it is a protocol, not a crypto primitive). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517476/tls-1-2-java-1-6-bouncycastle for details for to use BC for TLS.

Comment: Hi Robert, I tried the indicated code but I'm receiving the error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unknown cert org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.Certificate@42552c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do TLS with BouncyCastle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065170/how-do-i-do-tls-with-bouncycastle)