# Initializing SSLContext with KeyManager and TrustManager as null is harmful? Does it still do sslhandshakes?

Tags: ssl, httpsurlconnection, sslcontext

I am very new to work in SSL Certificates, in java. By default java8 does TLSv1.2, but for some reasons, the app that i work on needs to set SSLcontext to TLSv1.2 explicitly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121510/java-httpsurlconnection-and-tls-1-2/45752102) i found a steps clear. But it requires an array of KeyManager and TrustManager which looks more time for me to understand what and how it works. Sure i will learn it, But for a quick solution i use the below code and it works. But is this harmful? Does it still do SSLHandshakes and creates a secure communication?

```
   SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
   sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not point in initializing an SSLContext without truststore or keystore managers. The main reason for using HTTPS connection is because of its SSL/TLS connection which is much more secured due to its enhanced security.

With that being said, the java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init-javax.net.ssl.KeyManager:A-javax.net.ssl.TrustManager:A-java.security.SecureRandom-) clearly mentions either of the first two parameters has to be set.