# Enable Java to permit expired certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

Is there any command line flag(s) to enable Java to permit expired certificates?

Right now I'm getting the following exception as the Certificate is expired.

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: {PAST DATETIME}
at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:274)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:629)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:602)
at org.apache.ws.security.validate.SignatureTrustValidator.validateCertificates(SignatureTrustValidator.java:103)
```

I've tried the following command line flag which doesn't ignore Certificate Expiration check

```
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false
```

Our application is running in tomcat under path `/myapplication`. So I created another application `/ignorecertificate` and deployed in same Tomcat's webapp folder. As per the accepted answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201048/allowing-java-to-use-an-untrusted-certificate-for-ssl-https-connection), I run the following code in startup of `/ignoreexpired` application.

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }
};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Since both applications were deployed in same tomcat, I expected `/myapplication` to ignore certificate expiration check / exception (Bcoz both applications share the same java instance). But still it's not working. I run this ignore code in another application(`/ignoreexpired`) coz I don't want to make any changes in my current application(`/myapplication`).

Comment: The coder, you should accept his answer, it's a pretty good and informative one!  I know you likely just forgot considering your reputation, lol.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false
> ```

This option (with some additional config) allows online check to the certificate issuer on the revocation status of the certificate. Not what you're looking for.

> Since both applications were deployed in same tomcat, I expected /myapplication to ignore certificate expiration check / exception

Applications run in different JVM context. Changes in `TrustManager` of `/ignoreexpired` application will not affect the other one.

You can include the expired certificate in the truststore used by JVM. I think the `TrustoreManager` will not check expiration on certificates expressly included in the trust store. Create a JKS using keytool or GUI [KeyStore explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/), insert the certificate (the final certificate, not the root) and use it globally in tomcat through

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststorepassword
```

You can also update the default JVM truststore at `jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: Man, I totally did not know this neither did my manager/java coding boss but you are completely right.  Tested with JDK8 with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and I could see that the expired cert was found and also trusted!  Thanks!

Comment: @JGlass thank you for the "-Djavax.net.debug=all" part. So good to see all handshaking during these corona time ;)