# Allow insecure HTTPS connection for Java JDK 11 HttpClient

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client

Sometimes it is needed to allow insecure HTTPS connections, e.g. in some web-crawling applications which should work with any site. I used [one such solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201048/allowing-java-to-use-an-untrusted-certificate-for-ssl-https-connection) with old HttpsURLConnection API which was recently superseded by the [new HttpClient API](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) in JDK 11. What is the way to allow insecure HTTPS connections (self-signed or expired certificate) with this new API?

UPD: The code I tried (in Kotlin but maps directly to Java):

```
    val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object: X509TrustManager {
        override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate>? = null
        override fun checkClientTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}
        override fun checkServerTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}
    })

    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())

    val sslParams = SSLParameters()
    // This should prevent host validation
    sslParams.endpointIdentificationAlgorithm = ""

    httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        .sslParameters(sslParams)
        .build()
```

But on sending I have exception (trying on localhost with self-signed certificate):

```
java.io.IOException: No name matching localhost found
```

Using IP address instead of localhost gives "No subject alternative names present" exception.

After some debugging of JDK I found that `sslParams` are really ignored in the place the exception is thrown and some locally created instance is used. Further debugging revealed that the only way to affect the hostname verification algorithm is setting `jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification` system property to true. And that's seems to be a solution. `SSLParameters` in the code above have no effect so this part can be discarded. Making it configurable only globally looks like serious design flaw in new HttpClient API.

Comment: You need to instantiate an `SSLContext` that is going to ignore the bad certs, then use that to build the connection.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With Java 11, as well you can do a similar effort [as mentioned in the selected answer in the link shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1201102/1746118) with the `HttpClient` built as:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(<timeoutInSeconds> * 1000))
        .sslContext(sc) // SSL context 'sc' initialised as earlier
        .sslParameters(parameters) // ssl parameters if overriden
        .build();
```

with a sample request

```
HttpRequest requestBuilder = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://www.example.com/getSomething"))
            .GET()
            .build();
```

can be executed as:

```
httpClient.send(requestBuilder, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()); // sends the request
```

---

Update from comments, to disable the hostname verification, currently one can use the system property:

```
-Djdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification
```

which can be [set programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988677/allow-insecure-https-connection-for-java-jdk-11-httpclient/52995420?noredirect=1#comment93560348_52995420) as following :-

```
final Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
props.setProperty("jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
```

Comment: I found the solution and updated the question. Your answer is mostly valid so I accepted it. But also note that `jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification` system property must be set to get rid of hostname verification exceptions, SSLParameters unfortunately do not affect this behaviour, which is either bug or some strange design decision.

Comment: programatically disable hostname verification before instantiating httpclient

`// PREVENTS HOST VALIDATION`

`final Properties props = System.getProperties();`

`props.setProperty("jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification", Boolean.TRUE.toString());`

Comment: `jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification` is a system wide property - if you have _two_ clients under the same JVM: one that needs that disabled and one that needs that enabled...

Answer (score 34):

As suggested already you need an SSLContext which ignores the bad certificates. The exact code which obtains the SSLContext in one of the links in the question should work by basically creating a null TrustManager which doesn't look at the certs:

```
private static TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }
};

public static  void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        .build();
```

The problem with the above is obviously that server authentication is disabled completely for all sites. If there were only one bad certificate then you could import it into a keystore with:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore keystorename -storepass pass -alias cert -file certfile
```

and then initialize the SSLContext using an InputStream reading the keystore as follows:

```
char[] passphrase = ..
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(i, passphrase); // i is an InputStream reading the keystore

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
kmf.init(ks, passphrase);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
tmf.init(ks);

sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Either of the above solutions will work for a self-signed certificate. A third option is in the case where the server provides a valid, non self-signed certificate but for a host which does not match any of the names in the certificate it provides, then a system property  "jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification" can be set to "true" and this will force the certificate to be accepted in the same way that the HostnameVerifier API was used previously. Note, that in normal deployments it isn't expected that any of these mechanisms would be used, as it should be possible to automatically verify the certificate supplied by any correctly configured HTTPS server.

Answer (score 16):

Providing an X509TrustManager that does not do certificate verification (as in the answers above) is insufficient to disable hostname verification because the implementation of SSLContext "wraps" the provided X509TrustManager with an X509ExtendedTrustManager if it is not an X509ExtendedTrustManager.  The wrapping "Extended" X509ExtendedTrustManager performs hostname verification.

A way to avoid hostname verification therefore is to provide an X509ExtendedTrustManager that does not do hostname verification.  This may be done as follows:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager;

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(
    null,
    new TrustManager[]
    {
        new X509ExtendedTrustManager()
        {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
            {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] a_certificates,
                final String a_auth_type)
            {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] a_certificates,
                final String a_auth_type)
            {
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] a_certificates,
                final String a_auth_type,
                final Socket a_socket)
            {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] a_certificates,
                final String a_auth_type,
                final Socket a_socket)
            {
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] a_certificates,
                final String a_auth_type,
                final SSLEngine a_engine)
            {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                final X509Certificate[] a_certificates,
                final String a_auth_type,
                final SSLEngine a_engine)
            {
            }
        }
    },
    null);
```

Supply this SSLContext to the HTTPClient.Builder in the usual way (as shown in earlier answers).

This method has the benefit of applying on a per HttpClient basis (i.e. not JVM-wide).

Comment: This worked for me thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO, much better than disabling hostname verification globally.

Comment: This was the one and should definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, all the previous answers do more than just disable hostname verification. They disable certificate verification completely.

While these solutions work perfectly for development environments, they are not something you want to ever use in production.

Here's a solution that allows you to modify certificate in a way that you think is most suitable (e.g. replace SAN with another)

First a class that is used to wrap default TrustManager to intercept calls:

```
public class TrustManagers {
    /**
     * Create {@link TrustManager} wrapper that disables certificate hostname validation
     *
     * @param tm trust manager
     * @param altNames alternative subject names to allow
     * @return requested trustmanager
     */
    public static TrustManager disableHostnameValidation(
            TrustManager tm, Collection<X509SubjectAltName> altNames) {
        if (tm instanceof X509ExtendedTrustManager x509tm) {
            return new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    x509tm.checkServerTrusted(modifySAN(chain), authType);
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    x509tm.checkServerTrusted(modifySAN(chain), authType, socket);
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    x509tm.checkServerTrusted(modifySAN(chain), authType, engine);
                }

                private X509Certificate[] modifySAN(X509Certificate[] chain) {
                    if (chain.length < 1) {
                        return chain;
                    }
                    var result = new X509Certificate[chain.length];
                    System.arraycopy(chain, 0, result, 0, chain.length);
                    result[0] = new FixedSANX509Certificate(chain[0], altNames);
                    return result;
                }

                // only delegates below
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return x509tm.getAcceptedIssuers();
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    x509tm.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    x509tm.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType, socket);
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    x509tm.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
                }
            };
        }
        return tm;
    }
}
```

Then a class that allows you to modify certificate's contents. You are likely to be interested in SANs:

```
/**
 * X509Certificate with subject alternative names (SAN) added to list of SANs in certificate. This
 * effectively bypasses hostname validation, but allows other validations
 */
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FixedSANX509Certificate extends X509Certificate {
    private final X509Certificate cert;
    private final Collection<X509SubjectAltName> altNames;

    @Override
    public Collection<List<?>> getSubjectAlternativeNames() throws CertificateParsingException {
        return Stream.concat(
                        cert.getSubjectAlternativeNames().stream(),
                        altNames.stream()
                                .flatMap(
                                        altName ->
                                                Stream.of(
                                                        List.of(
                                                                altName.type().getCode(),
                                                                altName.value()))))
                .toList();
    }

    // only delegates below
    @Override
    public boolean hasUnsupportedCriticalExtension() {
        return cert.hasUnsupportedCriticalExtension();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getCriticalExtensionOIDs() {
        return cert.getCriticalExtensionOIDs();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return cert.equals(other);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getNonCriticalExtensionOIDs() {
        return cert.getNonCriticalExtensionOIDs();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return cert.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void checkValidity()
            throws CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException {
        cert.checkValidity();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getEncoded() throws CertificateEncodingException {
        return cert.getEncoded();
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(PublicKey key)
            throws CertificateException,
                    NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                    InvalidKeyException,
                    NoSuchProviderException,
                    SignatureException {
        cert.verify(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkValidity(Date date)
            throws CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException {
        cert.checkValidity(date);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getExtensionValue(String oid) {
        return cert.getExtensionValue(oid);
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(PublicKey key, String sigProvider)
            throws CertificateException,
                    NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                    InvalidKeyException,
                    NoSuchProviderException,
                    SignatureException {
        cert.verify(key, sigProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public int getVersion() {
        return cert.getVersion();
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger getSerialNumber() {
        return cert.getSerialNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getIssuerDN() {
        return cert.getIssuerDN();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return cert.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public PublicKey getPublicKey() {
        return cert.getPublicKey();
    }

    @Override
    public X500Principal getIssuerX500Principal() {
        return cert.getIssuerX500Principal();
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getSubjectDN() {
        return cert.getSubjectDN();
    }

    @Override
    public X500Principal getSubjectX500Principal() {
        return cert.getSubjectX500Principal();
    }

    @Override
    public Date getNotBefore() {
        return cert.getNotBefore();
    }

    @Override
    public Date getNotAfter() {
        return cert.getNotAfter();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getTBSCertificate() throws CertificateEncodingException {
        return cert.getTBSCertificate();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getSignature() {
        return cert.getSignature();
    }

    @Override
    public String getSigAlgName() {
        return cert.getSigAlgName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getSigAlgOID() {
        return cert.getSigAlgOID();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getSigAlgParams() {
        return cert.getSigAlgParams();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean[] getIssuerUniqueID() {
        return cert.getIssuerUniqueID();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean[] getSubjectUniqueID() {
        return cert.getSubjectUniqueID();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean[] getKeyUsage() {
        return cert.getKeyUsage();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getExtendedKeyUsage() throws CertificateParsingException {
        return cert.getExtendedKeyUsage();
    }

    @Override
    public int getBasicConstraints() {
        return cert.getBasicConstraints();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<List<?>> getIssuerAlternativeNames() throws CertificateParsingException {
        return cert.getIssuerAlternativeNames();
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(PublicKey key, Provider sigProvider)
            throws CertificateException,
                    NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                    InvalidKeyException,
                    SignatureException {
        cert.verify(key, sigProvider);
    }
}
```

Record and enum classes to make configuration less painful:

```
public record X509SubjectAltName(X509SubjectAltType type, String value) {}

/** SAN value types. Aligns with {@link X509Certificate#getSubjectAlternativeNames} */
public enum X509SubjectAltType {
    HOSTNAME(2),
    IP(7);

    final int code;

    private X509SubjectAltType(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

This would be used to create SSLContext like:

```
private SSLContext createSSLContext(Collection<X509SubjectAltName> altNames)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    var trustManagerFactory =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);

    var trustManagers =
            Stream.of(trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers())
                    .map(tm -> TrustManagers.disableHostnameValidation(tm, altNames))
                    .toArray(TrustManager[]::new);

    var sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);

    return sslContext;
}
```

And this is how you would allow connections to ip 1.2.3.4:

```
createSSLContext(List.of(new X509SubjectAltName(X509SubjectAltType.IP, "1.2.3.4")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before request:

```java
System.setProperty("jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification", "true");
```