# javax.net.ssl.SSLContext to trust everything sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), ???, new SecureRandom());

Tags: java

Small java question regarding the Java built in Http client please.

I have a small piece of code where I am trying the Java built in Http client.

```
final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = getAndInitKeyManagerFactory();
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
```

(Please note the null for `TrustManager[] tm`)

I would like to avoid carrying an extra truststore, and since this is mainly for testing, I am more than ok trusting any server even knowing this might be insecure.

Unfortunately, even with this null for the trust, I am still getting :

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching abc.com
```

I even tried giving a

```
static class InsecureTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }
    }

sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[] { new InsecureTrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());
```

But no luck, still the same exception with stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No subject alternative DNS name matching abc.com found.
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:565)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at question.Question.main(Question.java:54)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching abc.com found.
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
[...]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: abc.com found.
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:207)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:98)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:415)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1584)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1525)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1310)
```

I am not quite understanding the issue, and would like to ask what is the proper way to configure from the code, with Java built in, to trust everything.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the entire stack trace?

Comment: I should have pasted it, edited, and thanks David for pointing that out

Comment: If you don't want it secure why are you using SSL? NB It is not valid for `getAcceptedIssuers() to return null. Don't use this insecure code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your problem is only(!) hostname verification and not actual cert validation (like many other Qs), to avoid JSSE wrapping your `InsecureTrustManager` and adding the hostname verification, either you must 'implement' [X509ExtendedKeyManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html) instead -- and since this is an abstract class (it was designed before Java started allowing default methods in interfaces), you actually use `extends` and override its 4 (abstract) methods in addition to the ones in `X509TrustManager` -- or else turn it off specifically with `jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification` in which case you don't need a custom TrustManager at all.

Effectively dupe [Allow insecure HTTPS connection for Java JDK 11 HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988677/allow-insecure-https-connection-for-java-jdk-11-httpclient) particularly 'Update' in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995420/2868801 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70741993/2868801

and [Java SSL: how to disable hostname verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031258/java-ssl-how-to-disable-hostname-verification) particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/54513917/2868801 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70604898/2868801

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace, if you want to avoid the check, you need to implement your own instance of `X509TrustManager` i.e. what `X509TrustManagerImpl` implements. This is the class that's throwing the error.