# What's meaning of client SSL authentication and server SSL authentication in X509TrustManager?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, x509, x509trustmanager

I understand "certificate chain provided by the peer", if certificate provided by the peer is in the X509TrustManager, the certificate is trusted, so is it just need a checkTrusted instead of checkClientTrusted and checkServerTrusted, i don't understand what's the difference? Can anyone explains?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html

void    checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType):

Given the partial or complete certificate chain provided by the peer, build a certificate path to a trusted root and return if it can be validated and is trusted for **client SSL authentication** based on the authentication type.

void    checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType):

Given the partial or complete certificate chain provided by the peer, build a certificate path to a trusted root and return if it can be validated and is trusted for **server SSL authentication** based on the authentication type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early SSL/TLS protocols that existed when JSSE was designed, there was a significant difference between the constraints on and thus validation of server cert (linked to the key_exchange portion of the ciphersuite) versus client cert (mostly independent of key_exchange but controlled by CertReq); see rfc2246 7.4.2 and 7.4.4 (modified by rfc4492 2 and 3). Although authType is a `String` in both `checkServer` and `checkClient`, the values in it and the processing of them in the default TrustManager were significantly different.

TLS1.2, implemented (along with 1.1) by Java 7 and early 8, changed the cert constraints to also use a new signature_algorithms extension (from client) and field (from server) in combination with the prior fields. As a result in Java 7 up the interface you link is functionally replaced by a subtype class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html which in addition to the new constraint checks also moves to the JSSE layer only in `checkServer` the hostname checking aka endpoint identification formerly done at a higher level like `HttpsURLConnection` (if at all). The extended class additionally takes an `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` argument (as applicable) which allows access to the additional information for sigalgs and hostname.

Finally TLS1.3, implemented in java 11 up and backported to 8u261 up, uses *only* extensions, now two of them, and not the ciphersuite at all, for cert selection and checking. In 1.3 the extended API is still called but the value in `authType` is meaningless and must not be used, and in at least some cases I have looked at is in fact empty, so the actual (rfc5280) validation is in fact the same for both directions. But as above `checkServer` does endpoint identification if applicable while `checkClient` does not.

See an actual difference in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158339/ssl-tls-certificate-chain-validation-result-in-invalid-authentication-type-d (note: 2017 was before TLS1.3 existed)
and compare [javax.net.ssl.SSLContext to trust everything sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), ???, new SecureRandom());](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092532/javax.net.ssl.sslcontext-to-trust-everything) .