# Spring WebSocketClient / StandardWebsocketClient - How to allow insecure https/wss connections?

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket

I've poured over Spring's documentation, and I can't seem to find any hints.

Also, there are a lot of notes / samples of how to handle invalid / self signed certs for Spring's HttpClient. However, none of them seem to work when attempting a client websocket connection.

By looking at the build logs below, it seems that Spring builds this in a tomcat container, and then sends it to java.base/sun.security.ssl, which why I suspect that all the HttpClient workarounds don't work.

Right now, this is proof of concept / building block work. The target server will eventually have valid certs, but I need to make it work in the lab first. Getting a valid cert on the server really isn't an option at the moment.

Help!

My code:

```
package com.foo.cmw.websockClient;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class SvxWebClient implements ISVXwebSockClient {

    private URI uri;
    private final WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    private final WebSocketHandler handler = new InboundMessageHandler();
    private final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
    public WebSocketSession session;
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    public SvxWebClient(String uri) {
        try {
            this.uri = new URI(uri);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() {

        CompletableFuture<WebSocketSession> sessionFuture = client.execute(handler, headers, uri);
        try {
            this.session = sessionFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void send(Object rpc) {
        String jsonString;
        try {
            jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(rpc);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(jsonString));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public void setUri(URI uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

Build log:

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)

2023-09-27T17:54:02.633-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.cmw.WebsocketClientApplication       : Starting WebsocketClientApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 101935 (/home/allen/moshJava/websocketClient/target/classes started by allen in /home/allen/moshJava/websocketClient)
2023-09-27T17:54:02.637-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.cmw.WebsocketClientApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-27T17:54:02.697-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-09-27T17:54:02.698-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-09-27T17:54:03.431-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-27T17:54:03.492-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2023-09-27T17:54:03.781-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-27T17:54:03.789-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-27T17:54:03.790-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.13]
2023-09-27T17:54:03.838-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-27T17:54:03.839-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1140 ms
2023-09-27T17:54:04.172-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-09-27T17:54:04.199-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-27T17:54:04.216-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.cmw.WebsocketClientApplication       : Started WebsocketClientApplication in 1.947 seconds (process running for 2.703)
2023-09-27T17:54:04.513-05:00  INFO 101935 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-27T17:54:04.527-05:00 ERROR 101935 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [wss://switchvox.wurmborn.org/rtapiws] failed
    at com.foo.cmw.websockClient.SvxWebClient.connect(SvxWebClient.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.foo.cmw.WebsocketClientApplication.run(WebsocketClientApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:348) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:233) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$started$5(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:76) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.started(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:76) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.foo.cmw.WebsocketClientApplication.main(WebsocketClientApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [wss://switchvox.wurmborn.org/rtapiws] failed
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[na:na]
    at com.foo.cmw.websockClient.SvxWebClient.connect(SvxWebClient.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [wss://switchvox.wurmborn.org/rtapiws] failed
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:429) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.lambda$executeInternal$0(StandardWebSocketClient.java:150) ~[spring-websocket-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$toSupplier$0(FutureUtils.java:74) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:492) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:321) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WebSocketSslHandshakeThread.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632) ~[na:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

**Links I've already looked at:**

[Allow insecure HTTPS connection for Java JDK 11 HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988677/allow-insecure-https-connection-for-java-jdk-11-httpclient)

https://www.javacodemonk.com/allow-insecure-ssl-in-java-11-httpclient-6e677c76

[Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

[Disabling SSL Certificate Validation in Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072585/disabling-ssl-certificate-validation-in-spring-resttemplate)