# Ignore SSL certificate validation when using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate, spring-web

I am using Spring RestTemplate to make HTTPS requests, and I want to ignore SSL certificate

Here is my code to create the restTemplate request:

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String 
authType) -> true;
SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
.loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
.build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new 
SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
loseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
.setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
.build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
...
response = restTemplate.exchange("https://192.168.1.2:/foo/bar", 
HttpMethod.POST, entity,String.class);
```

This request works when I use the server hostname, 
But I get the following Exception when I use the server IP address:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST 
request for "https://192.168.1.2/foo/bar": Certificate for 
<192.168.1.2> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []; 
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate 
for <192.168.1.2> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for 
<192.168.1.2> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Allowing Java to use an untrusted certificate for SSL/HTTPS connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201048/allowing-java-to-use-an-untrusted-certificate-for-ssl-https-connection)?

Answer (score 7):

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws GeneralSecurityException {

    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("https", sslsf).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();

    BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(
            socketFactoryRegistry);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some details on why this fixes the issue.

Comment: use: (> 4.4) implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'