# Spring boot using https only - Test failing

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have spring boot - angular application

My server port is 1234 (example).

But now I have setup ssl

**Steps:**

created self signed cert using keytool and added my p12 cert file into resources folder

updated application.properties

> server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
>
> server.ssl.key-store=classpath:myfile.p12
>
> server.ssl.key-store-password=somepasswordfromenv
>
> server.ssl.key-alias=myalias
>
> server.ssl.enabled=true

> http.port=8080

> server.port=8443

Started app and tested

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppWithoutBeansApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class AppControllerTest {

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
    private Resource trustStore;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
    private String trustStorePassword;

@Test
public void givenAcceptingAllCertificatesUsing4_4_whenUsingRestTemplate_thenCorrect() 
throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    
    String urlOverHttps = "https://localhost:8443/";
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient
      = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
        .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory 
      = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    ResponseEntity<String> response 
      = new RestTemplate(requestFactory).exchange(
      urlOverHttps, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode().value(), equalTo(200));
}
```

...

Error:

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/": Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:746)

Don't understand how my integration test works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All answers looked similar, but this one worked

[Ignore SSL certificate validation when using Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038334/ignore-ssl-certificate-validation-when-using-spring-resttemplate)

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws GeneralSecurityException {

    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("https", sslsf).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();

    BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(
            socketFactoryRegistry);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Looks like this part made the difference

```
 *Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("https", sslsf).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();*
```

DO NOT USE THIS

```
//  @Bean
//    public RestTemplate nonsslrestTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
//         TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
//         SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
//         SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
//         CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
//         HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
//         requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
//       return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
//    }
```